# Could an alternative form of photosynthesis be much more efficient?

Tags: flora, utopia

I'm worldbuilding a whimsical, leisurely world where the livin is easy. I was thinking about, "[What would put agriculture/industry on Easy Mode?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246565/what-one-change-would-put-life-on-easy-mode)"

One answer that suggests itself is increasing [photosynthetic efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency): plants are the basis of most goods (food, fuel, fiber, even meat), and if they could capture more incoming energy, people would have more of everything.

Doing some research on this question led me to C3, C4, and CAM plants. [There is already work done to make C3 plants C4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_carbon_fixation#Converting_C3_plants_to_C4). Is this the route to go down for my worldbuilding? Should I make all plants in the world C4 producers? Or is that impossible or detrimental for some reason I've overlooked?

Another possibility: I found [this research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_carbon_fixation#Synthetic_glycolate_pathway) about adding enzymes that break down glyoxylate into CO₂ which is then reüsed instead of going to waste. "The end result is 24% more biomass."

Should I go with the glyoxylate-breakdown route? The C4-for-all route? Both? Other?

Comment: If you want to build a world that does X, **make it do X**. Don't spend forever and a day trying to justify why X can exist, because that's chronically unimportant.

Answer (score 9):

There is an easy method of increasing plant production: [more CO2.](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/ask-the-experts-does-rising-co2-benefit-plants1/)  A quote from that article:

> In those experiments artificially doubling CO2 from pre-industrial levels increased trees’ productivity by around 23 percent...

This [article](https://www.ontario.ca/page/supplemental-carbon-dioxide-greenhouses) includes tests on the net effect on crops in greenhouses, showing that the optimal level for most plants is in the range 1000 to 1300 ppm, compared to the typical outdoor values of round-about 340 ppm. That is, three to four times the ordinary values.

Many species of plants originated during periods with much higher CO2. Now that CO2 levels are rising due to industrialization, [the entire planet is greening.](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/carbon-dioxide-fertilization-greening-earth)  One can almost imagine the forests saying "Oh! It's a delightful breath of stale fetid air! Mmmmmm!"

By the way, humans are OK with [that sort of level.](https://www.health.state.mn.us/communities/environment/air/toxins/co2.html#:%7E:text=At%20even%20higher%20levels%20of,dangerous%20to%20life%20and%20health.) It may require some adaptation and acclimation. But they are not dangerous to health. Humans start to have effects round about 5000 ppm.

Comment: This is a good idea. I've actually used it in greenhouses before.

Comment: I think humans are demonstrably affected (in a 'negative' way) by higher CO2 concentration starting from only 800 ppm. The problems are of the cognitive kind. (Hence the recommendation to regularly vent classrooms etc.)

Comment: The study about the greening earth sounds a fake. 1) The image shows as green urban area. 2) Arable land which makes up the vast majority of the Earth surface is green only for some periods of time. 3) Logged land. Turning forest to brush reduces greening, but is not visible. 4) Roads, rail and other transport infrastructure, like urban areas, in that image are not visible. Are they counted as green as well?

Comment: Still about the fake study. The concentration of CO2 as a percentage is increasing because the relative initial value was small. But in absolute terms it did not increase so much that it could so dramatically affect plant growth.

Comment: @FluidCode A google search would show that it was NASA who noticed that there is 5% more foliage now then there was 20 years ago... Forbes also reports on this, as does Phys.org.. https://www.nasa.gov/feature/greening-of-the-earth-mitigates-surface-warming

Comment: @FluidCode Just realized that Boba Fit already linked to the NASA article... You made a comment without clicking on the link and realizing "Oh, this article was written by NASA, one of the most reputable scientific organizations in the world... Its probably true." And instead jumped to "It is fake... Good job...

Comment: Finally, the "fake study"... not fake, piping extra Co2 to plants increases their growth, this has been replicated by scientists all over the place...  All of the arguments against this claim say "This claim is true but.... you should be worried anyway because of reasons"...  Dude, before claiming something is fake do some research.

Comment: @Questor Yes I was commenting the NASA article and I do not worship the sources. I use the scientific method and evaluate how reasonable the research is without any *ipse dixit*. The flaws in that research are clear.

Comment: @Questor The studies carried out in closed greenhouses do not prove what is happening at planet level. 1) The concentration of CO2 are not the Same. 2) They do not take into accout expansion of urban areas and slash an burn to expand arable land.

Comment: @FluidCode Just realized that I am not smart enough of a person to disagree with you.... Perhaps no one is as you seem to be in class of your own. Best of luck.

Answer (score 7):

The metric of "efficiency" doesn't exist in a vacuum. [CAM photosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassulacean_acid_metabolism) works well in hot, arid conditions when plants using other systems risk being dried out. Even in the C<sub>3</sub> to C<sub>4</sub> link you gave above, you can see notes like "*C<sub>2</sub> photosynthesis... has the advantage of requiring fewer steps of genetic engineering and performing better than C<sub>3</sub> under all temperatures and light levels.*" which under some circumstances can make it a better choice than C<sub>4</sub>, especially for higher latitudes. You don't say anything about the climate in which your plants are growing, but it makes a big difference here!

Plausibly, your future genetic engineers might be using *all* the techniques they can usefully combine in order to maximize yields under some particular set of conditions. We don't know what that combination of modifications could be, because we haven't tried them yet. A reasonable assumption is probably to pick one or other of the things you linked that are actually being experimented with in the real world.

The *safest* solution is to not mention the technical details *at all*, because there's scope for getting stuff unambiguously wrong in making such claims and there's no real benefit to your story or setting.

Answer (score -2):

**No, it couldn't.**

Just capturing more carbon is not enough. For more biomass, the plants would require correspondingly more of other nutrients as well, which would become a new limiting factor because improved photosynthesis does not create more of *them*.

Comment: Yes it could. "_The end result is 24% more biomass_" is a quote from a real-world study, linked in the OP.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, thank you. No, it couldn't; the 24% increase in biomass required germinating the plants in a greenhouse in a pot filled with a soil mix, then transplanting them into prepared plots, spacing the plants just right, and watering 'as needed'. You neglected these inputs though; no wonder efficiency *appears* higher to you.

Comment: And yet simliar plants grown in the same circumstances _without_ the modification did _not_ have substantial additional biomass, despite the other circumstances. This is because the efficiency of production of biomass in the modified plants is higher given the same nutrient sources.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, thank you. That just means that for the modified plants, even more nutrients would need to be artificially provided to replenish those taken up from the soil, or else they will become unable to produce this additional biomass. Either way their efficiency drops back to what it was.

Comment: Your answer assumes that growth is already bottlenecked by other nutrients. It's possible for this to be so, but will not always be so.

Comment: @ihaveideas increased nutrient requirements could just mean that forests look less like european/american forests. MinuteEarth did a video on how most tropical areas have increased biodiversity because of the lack of nutrients while european forests with plenty of nutrients have many of the same trees.

Assuming the soil characteristics of this world are equal, the forests will just look more diverse, like a tropical rainforest does, as the lack of nutrients increases competition. And areas that would naturally be less nutrient rich which would be shrubland here, on this world it's grassland

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, growth is always bottlenecked by whatever resource happens to be in the shortest supply compared to requirements. It's called Liebig's law of the minimum. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liebig%27s_law_of_the_minimum)

Comment: @Katy, thank you. Did you ever wonder why the tropical rainforests did not expand into the temperate zones? I mean, there's all these nutrients in the soils there, just sitting and waiting to be taken up... ;)

Comment: @ihaveideas It's because there is so many resources that one, more quickly growing species of tree will quickly grow and smother any other competition. It's hard for me to wrap my head around, but it seems that competition works best on limited resources, when there's plenty there will be a handful of winners. (I could probably make that into an analogy for our world's inequality, but let's not.)

So, I see this as being fairly reasonable for this world, and increased biodiversity could make some seriously cool scenery!

Comment: @Katy, thank you. It's easier to understand by keeping in mind that there is not just one limiting factor. Tropical rainforest needs nutrients *and* water *and* high temperature year-round *and* high insolation; take away any one of these things and its supposed higher efficiency drops to zero *because it can no longer grow*. Going back to the original conversation, more efficient photosynthesis does not lift any of these limits; it just makes the plants reach them quicker. For a real-life example, consider how weeds grow quickly only to eventually be outcompeted by other plants.

Comment: @ihaveideas good point, it's easy to get carried away and say x is the reason, clearly there's many reasons for the biodiversity of rainforests. I shouldn't've been so direct in my wording, because there's an exemption to every rule, and those exemptions have their own rules, and those rules themselves have their own exemptions... etc.